# Why does the input type text not appear when I code it in React? It has the closing tag, so it should work

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to add multiple text fields with a React State, but on the first step, I realized that the text field was not rendering. I don't know why.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
function Input() {
  var [firstName, setUserInput] = useState('');
   function handleUserInput(e) {
    setUserInput(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>First Name: </label>
          <input id="firstName" type="text" onChange={handleUserInput} value={firstName}/>
          <input type="text"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>First Name: </h1>
        <p>{firstName}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see issue with the code. But I don't see Input component being exported so can u please make sure that you are exporting the Input Component and import it to the right file in your application.

To export Input component simply do this.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
function Input() {
  var [firstName, setUserInput] = useState("");
  function handleUserInput(e) {
    setUserInput(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form>
          <label>First Name: </label>
          <input
            id="firstName"
            type="text"
            onChange={handleUserInput}
            value={firstName}
          />
          <input type="text" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>First Name: </h1>
        <p>{firstName}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Input;
```

And to import it to the file where you want to render it.

Comment: But I wanted 2 text fields, not one. That's the issue.

Comment: I can see them rendering in my app side by side. Please tell me what exactly are you trying to achieve so that I can help you batter.